# Adding Search field , icon & header to Drawer using MUI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Mui react.I'm working on drawer component using Mui react. Is it possible to add icon & organisation name & search field as shown in below image using Mui react in Drawer?I want to add logo & search field to the drawer how do i achieve it. Below is my code & the image i'm trying to achieve . Thanks.
[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import muiTheme from '../../../.storybook/muiTheme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

type Anchor = 'top' | 'left' | 'bottom' | 'right';

export const Drawers = ({ }) => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        top: false,
        left: false,
        bottom: false,
        right: false,
    });

    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
    };

    const list = (anchor) => (
        <Box
            sx={{ width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250 }}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
                {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </Box>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {['left'].map((anchor) => (
                <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
                    <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
                    <Drawer
                        anchor={anchor}
                        open={state[anchor]}
                        onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
                    >
                        {list(anchor)}
                    </Drawer>
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export const Temporary = Drawers.bind({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by just adding it to the `<Box>` Item in your `list(anchor)` function.
So I would probably look something like this:

```
const list = (anchor) => (
    <Box
        sx={{ width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250 }}
        role="presentation"
        onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    > 
    <TextField variant="filled" placeholder="" fullWidth pl={2} pr={2} />
    <List>
        ...
    </List>
</Box>
);
```